# Request and download a zip file from Open Subtitles in Python

Tags: html, python-3.x, python-requests, http-headers, urllib3

Hey I'm trying to download subtitles using a python script
Let's take [this](https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/subtitles/8057461/terminator-dark-fate-he) movie subtitles for example if you try and click one of the numbers of downloads for a specific subtitle, it will instantly download it as a zip file. 
But if you open the href link in a different tab it won't download you have to click it.
How is it possible to download it using requests or urllib?

This is what I have at the moment:

```
r = requests.get(link)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
z.extractall(os.getcwd() + '\\movies\\' + movie_name1 + ".zip")
```

Comment: try https://github.com/agonzalezro/python-opensubtitles

Answer (score 0):

The download link for opensubtitles is
"https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/download/vrf-108d030f/sub/{site_id}"

Comment: that `vrf-108d030f` part looks like it might be some kind of ID or something. are you sure this doesnt change between requests?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Been using it myself these past few days.